# SQL Query Sequential Month Logins

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have the following SQL table

| username | Month |
| --- | --- |
| 292 | 10 |
| 123 | 12 |
| 123 | 1 |
| 123 | 2 |
| 123 | 4 |
| 345 | 6 |
| 345 | 7 |

I want to query it, to get each username's login streak in Count of sequential Month. meaning the end result I am looking for looks like this :

| username | Streak |
| --- | --- |
| 292 | 1 |
| 123 | 3 |
| 345 | 2 |

How can I achieve it ? taking into note the Month 12 --> Month 1 issue;

Appreciate your help;

Comment: How could you tell if the Month 12 (say Dec-2021) on the row is just before Month 1 on another row (say Jan-2020); you need proper dates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would give you the result you want:

```
select username, count(*)
from (
    select 
    username
    , month_1
    , coalesce(nullif(lead(month_1) 
                      over (partition by username 
                            order by coalesce(nullif(month_1,12),0))
                      - coalesce(nullif(month_1,12),0),-1),1) as MonthsTillNext
from login_tab 
  ) Step1
where MonthsTillNext=1
group by username
```

By calculating the difference from the next row, where the next row is defined as the next month_no in ascending order, treating 12 as 0 (refer to the ambiguity I mentioned in my comment). It then just leaves the rows for consecutive months rows, and counts them.

Beware though, in addition to the anomaly around month:12, there is another case not considered: if the months for the user are 1,2,3 and 6,7,8 this would count as Streak:6; is it what you wanted?

Comment: Since "With" was not supported via phpmyadmin, this solution worked like a charm, many thanks for lending me your brain :)

Answer (score 0):

One way would be with a recursive CTE, like

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte (username, month, cnt) AS
(
 SELECT username, month, 1
 FROM test
 UNION ALL
 SELECT test.username, test.month, cte.cnt+1
 FROM cte INNER JOIN test
  ON cte.username = test.username AND CASE WHEN cte.month = 12 THEN 1 ELSE cte.month + 1 END = test.month
)
SELECT username, MAX(cnt)
FROM cte
GROUP BY username
ORDER BY username
```

The idea is that the CTE (named `cte` in my example) recursively joins back to the table on a condition where the user is the same and the month is the next one. So for user 345, you have:

| Username | Month | Cnt |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 345 | 6 | 1 |
| 345 | 7 | 1 |
| 345 | 7 | 2 |

The rows with cnt=1 are from the original table (with the extra `cnt` column hardcoded to 1), the row with cnt=2 is from the recursive part of the query (which found a match and used `cnt+1` for its cnt). The query then selects the maximum for each user.

The join uses a `CASE` statement to handle 12 being followed by 1.

You can see it [working with your sample data in this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=de37c18c9208ca7a6b1d8ab7bd5c4bb5).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the prompt reply; I tried to run it but I am stuck at unrecognized statement type (near with) - I am running Server version: 8.0.22 - MySQL Community Server - GPL. Any idea why ?

Comment: I do not know why. I thought all versions 8.0+ supported CTEs, but possibly recursive CTEs weren't supported until later. Sorry this didn't help you, but I'll leave it up since based on the DB Fiddle I do think it works on at least some versions... maybe it will help someone else.

Answer (score 0):

The one shared by @EdmCoff is quite elegant.

Another one without recursive and just using conditional logic -

```
with data_cte as
(
select username, month_1,
case when (count(month_1) over (partition by username) = 1) then 1
when (lead(month_1) over (partition by username order by username) - month_1) = 1  OR (month_1 - lag(month_1) over (partition by username order by username)) = 1 then 1
when (month_1 = 12 and min (month_1) over (partition by username) =1) then 1
end cnt
from login_tab 
  )
  select username, count(cnt) from data_cte group by username
```

DB Fiddle [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/36Jh5fuRUsoCxnr5G3WVp9/0).